# Unknown props on React Datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

On `React Datepicker` package, when using the component like so:

```
return <DatePicker
            dateFormat={formats.DATEFORMAT_DDMMYYYY_UPPERCASE_DASH}
            selected={this.state.selectedDate}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className='form-control'
            disabled={this.props.disabled}
        />;
```

I get following error message:

[image]

I cannot seem to find a fix for this issue. Has anyone else encountered this before?

Also as far as version goes, from package.json:

```
"react-datepicker": "^0.27.0",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [closed issue](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/517) that happened when using React Datepicker 0.27 and updating React to React 15.2. You can probably solve this updating React-Datepicker to the last version (0.44).

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you!